# Why is my timer using Date().getTime() not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a simple timer for a game I've been working on as a hobby, and every time I update the value of the timer, it has been reset! Can somebody tell me why this is?

```
var points = 0;
var timeLeft = 100000;
var timeOver = 0;

function tick() {
  ....
  checkTimes();
  updateScore();

};

function updateScore() {
 var score = document.getElementById("score");
 score.innerHTML = points;
 setTimes();
};

function setTimes(){
  var giveTime = 100000;
  if(points>1){
    giveTime = 10000 - (points*0.05);
  }
  timeOver = new Date().getTime() + giveTime;
};

function checkTimes(){
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  timeLeft = timeOver - now;
 var time = document.getElementById('time');
  time.innerHTML = parseInt(timeLeft/1000)+"."+(timeLeft%1000);


  if(now >= timeOver){
    gameOver();
  }

  else{}


};
```

Comment: Not sure why this received a close vote.

Comment: why not use Date.now() instead

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"every time I update the value of the timer, it has been reset!"* What value did you expect? What was the actual value?

Comment: Where and when are `setTimes()` and `checkTimes()` called?

Comment: the element timer is a number on screen that is suppose to count down, but every time it is updated it is something like 99.9##.

Comment: Going to need the rest of your code.

Comment: Just added all the relevant code. the id's and everything are spelled correctly

Comment: What does this have in common with html tag?

Comment: Why `parseInt(timeLeft/1000)`? If you want to truncate the value, either use `Math.floor` or `|0`, whichever suits.

Answer (score 0):

It may come from your `else{}`, I think you must loop the function in it. But we all agree that you must give us more code

```
function checkTimes(){ 
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    timeLeft = timeOver - now;
    var time = document.getElementById('time');
    time.innerHTML = parseInt(timeLeft/1000)+"."+(timeLeft%1000);


    if (now >= timeOver) { 
        gameOver();

    } else {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        timeLeft = timeOver - now;
        var time = document.getElementById('time');
        time.innerHTML = parseInt(timeLeft/1000) + "." + (timeLeft % 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's clearly code missing from what he posted, but this could be the problem. It remains unclear based on what has been posted. If `points` is unset, then its value would be `undefined`. `if (points > 1)` would evaluate false, and `timeOver` would be set to `now + 100000` everytime `setTimes` is called.

Comment: @crush: If `points` is undeclared, it would result in a *ReferenceError*, because he's reading it. Implicit declaration only works when writing to an undeclared variable. But you're right. There's certainly missing code.

Comment: @squint True. Good catch. So we know it must be declared somewhere since he is not reporting such error.

Answer (score 0):

The timer is reset every time because points never change... Looking at the code, I can't say with certain where points should increase or decrease, but you got my "point" :)

Comment: Points change when a player scores in game, however once you have 2 or more points, instead of 99.9##, the timer hops down to 9.9## and gets lower as the score continues to increase